# Strange signal on minus DC contact

Tags: power-supply, ac, dc, oscilloscope, ac-dc

It should be -11V, but the oscilloscope shows something like this:
[image: -11V, with 100Hz frequency and high amplitude]
The frequency of this 'signal' is 100 Hz.
And for the +11V it seems to be normal:
[image: +11V, quite normal]

If I understand everything correctly, the input is 220V with 50Hz.

This shape can be obtained only when load is present.

What can be the cause of this behavior?

***UPDATE***

It was the capacitor - it was too old, so, replacing it solve the DC power supply problem.

Comment: What is the device producing these outputs? Even better, provide a schematic of the circuit producing the -11 V output.

Comment: @ThePhoton I am afraid, schematics are unavailable, it is power supply for scientific equipment, quite old. Actually, at the moment, I am looking for schematics or any additional information.

Comment: You are picking up the mains hum. There can be thousands of reasons, without a schematic its impossible to pinpoint the part of the schematic that does this.

Comment: For an old power supply it very well may be the capacitors (electrolytic) that have dried out and no longer hold charge.  (Or other-wise failed.)

Comment: The best question is how do you measure negative terminal. In relation to what?

Comment: @Gregory Kornblum to the ground. Also can be measured just using one contact from oscilloscope (but with more noisy baseline).

Comment: @George Herold and when there is no load it is similar to the normal DC...

Comment: Химик, тогда надо выбросить и купить новый..

Comment: @Gregory Kornblum  Для специфичной электроники это не так просто + может виноват не блок питание, а потребитель. Сейчас это выясняем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100 Hz is indicative of ripple caused by a faulty capacitor after the bridge rectifier. That capacitor would normally smooth the bridge voltage so either it has failed open circuit or has gone leaky (a lot leaky).

There could be other reasons but this is a strong candidate. Old electrolytic caps are somewhat known to do this.

Comment: Nailed it. Either faulty or totally non-existent or disconnected.

Comment: @Andy aka And this shape of DC is only on load. Without any load it is similar to normal DC.

Comment: @Andy aka  This was exactly capacitor fault. After replacing it, all the ripples gone.